# Computing the definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Compute the value of the following definite integral: $$5050\left(\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^1 (1-x^{50} )^{100} dx} {\displaystyle\int_0^1 (1-x^{50})^{101} dx}\right)$$

Comment: @JaideepKhare This is an old JEE problem which has been asked almost everywhere on the internet. Here's a related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710265/find-the-ratio-of-frac-int-01-left1-x50-right100-dx-int-0, but I'm sure I have seen it in another post as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> $$ \text{Let} : I_n = \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^{50})^{n} dx$$

$$5050\left( \frac{\int_0^1 (1-x^{50} )^{100} dx} {\int_0^1 (1-x^{50})^{101} dx}\right)=5050\frac{I_{100}}{I_{101}}$$

$$I_{101}= \int_{0}^{1} (\color{red}1-\color{blue}{x^{50}})(1-x^{50})^{100}$$

$$I_{101}= \int_{0}^{1} (\color{red}1)(1-{x^{50}})^{100}-
\int_{0}^{1}(\color{blue}{x^{50}})(1-x^{50})^{100}$$

$$I_{101}=I_{100}-\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1} \color{blue}x \cdot x^{49}(1-x^{50})^{100}}_{\text{Integration by parts}} $$

$$I_{101} = I_{100} - \Bigg [\color{blue}{x}\int x^{49}(1-x^{50})^{100} - \int\frac{d}{dx}\color{blue}x \frac{(1-x^{50})^{101}}{5050} \Bigg ]_{0}^{1}$$

Now Let $(1-x^{50})=t \implies -50x^{49} dx = dt$
$$I_{101}=I_{100}-\Bigg[
~~ \underbrace{~\frac{-\color{blue}x(1-x^{50})^{101}}{101} 
\Bigg|_{0}^{1}}_{=0}-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-x^{50})^{101}}{5050}\Bigg]$$

$$I_{101}=I_{100}-\frac{I_{101}}{5050} $$

$$I_{101}+\frac{I_{101}}{5050}=I_{100}$$

$$\frac{5051}{5050}I_{101}=I_{100}$$

$$\implies 5050\frac{I_{100}}{I_{101}}=5051$$

Answer (score 2):

> $$\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^{50})^k dx$$

Let $x^{50}=u$ then we have, $50x^{49} dx=du$. So that $50u^{\frac{49}{50}} dx=du$. Hence we get,

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{50}u^{-\frac{49}{50}}(1-u)^k du$$

$$=\frac{1}{50}B(\frac{1}{50},k+1)$$

$$=\frac{1}{50} \frac{\Gamma (\frac{1}{50}) \Gamma (k+1)}{\Gamma (\frac{1}{50}+k+1)}$$

$$=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{51}{50})\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{51}{50}+k)}$$

In particular if $k$ is a positive integer we may write,

$$\Gamma(x+k)$$

$$=\Gamma(x+k-1+1)$$

$$=(x+k-1)\Gamma(x+k-1)$$

$$=(x+k-1)(x+k-2)...\Gamma(x+k-k)$$

$$=\Gamma(x) \prod_{n=1}^{k} (x+k-n)$$

To get,

$$\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^{50})^k dx$$

$$=\frac{k!}{\prod_{n=1}^{k} (\frac{51}{50}+k-n)}$$

Comment: This answer does not deserve a down vote. IMHO. (+1)

Comment: Thank you for neutralizing, none of the answers in my opinion deserve a down-vote.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Yes you are right, I too got downvote, not only one but two! The reason is a very big mystery, probably a revenge downvote?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. By the change of variable $t=x^{50}$, $dx=\dfrac1{50}t^{1/50-1}dt$, one gets
$$
\int_0^1 (1-x^{50})^{100}dx=\frac1{50}\int_0^1 (1-t)^{101-1}t^{1/50-1}dt
$$ then one may use the [Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function),
$$
\int_0^1 (1-t)^{a-1}t^{b-1}dt=\frac{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (b)}{\Gamma (a+b)}.
$$Can you finish it?